# How do I listen/catch success events of social media sharing using Android Share Intent Chooser (ACTION_SEND)?

Tags: java, android, events, android-intent, listener

I am using Intent ACTION_SEND to share a content in different social media. [image]

Now, disregarding other apps in there leaving twitter, facebook, instagram, How will I know if the shares have been successfully posted? Is there some kind of listener for it? Or are there intent for result features for it? Here's the Intent code

```
public static void shareTo(String type, String mediaPath, String caption, Context context) {


    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);


    share.setType(type);


    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);


    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);


    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sorry. You don't get any feedback on what the recipient of an `ACTION_SEND` intent does with it.

Comment: :( I guess right, That's quite sad. . Then exploring each of the App's API is the only choice left

Comment: It is possible with Intent.createChooser, check out this answer by commonsware. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203659

Answer (score 0):

`ACTION_SEND` does not return any callback however some work around is below that works perfect for me.

```
int action_type=-1;

shareData()
{
   action_type=1;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(action_type==1)
    {
        loadInterstitialAd();
        action_type=-1;
    }
}
```

Chill Pill :)