# Android share - keep track of the receiving app

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have implemented a share button in my app.

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

What am I looking for, is how to keep track of which application my user send this information to (i.e. the receiving app)?

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412432/how-to-get-callback-of-acion-send-intent

Comment: Code example with the solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43668105/2855857