# returnActivity events when calling startActivity method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an `Activity` and I start an appliction chooser with `startActivity`.

**Question**: How can I wait with the finishing the parent activity until the user has selected a preferred mail app?

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:" + "someone@mail.com")
                .buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("subject", "subject")
                .appendQueryParameter("body", "body")
                .build();

 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "chooser Title"));

 finish();
```

Comment: There is no callback for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203230/how-to-tell-which-app-was-selected-by-intent-createchooser), you could use IntentPicker instead of IntentChooser

```
Intent intentPick = new Intent();
intentPick.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
intentPick.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Launch using");
intentPick.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, emailIntent);
this.startActivityForResult(intentPick, REQUEST_CODE_MY_PICK);
// You have just started a picker activity,
```

Then you can listen for the result of the intent pick by adding the following callback method in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_MY_PICK) {
         // start the activity the user picked from the list
         startActivity(data);

         //you can finish() your activity here
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I avoid the issue for onActivityResult: "Annotations are not allowed here" ?

Comment: I guess you added the onActivityResult in a wrong place, for instance in another method. It should be directly in your activity class