# How can I know if the user selected an external app or pressed the back button in an action view intent?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I launch an intent for an action view to the user can choose an external app to open a certain file.How can I get the callback when the user selected an app ou pressed the back button?

Comment: I tried a startActivityForResult solution but it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32203659/115145