# Is there a way to track when the "Copy" link button is tapped in the Android system share sheet?

Tags: android, android-intent-chooser, android-sharesheet

Does anyone know if it's possible to track when the "Copy" link button is tapped in the Android system share sheet?

[image: Android system share sheet]

Using an [IntentSender](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data) and extracting the chosen component from the result bundle works great if the user chooses an app to share to, but that method doesn't work if the user taps "Copy" or "Nearby" since those options aren't external components.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203230/how-to-tell-which-app-was-selected-by-intent-createchooser

Comment: @Tiarait as mentioned in the post description, using an `IntentSender` won't work because they copy action doesn't launch an app