# How to know which app was selected by user when using an Intent chooser?

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-jetpack-compose, android-pendingintent, startactivityforresult

code:

```
    val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageURI)
        type = "image/jpeg"
    }

    val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, shareTxt)
    context.startActivity(shareIntent)
```

I want to get a callback and know which app was selected by user to share the Image. I am using jetpack compose so can we use rememberLauncherForActivityResult ?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/32203230/17664120